# How does a polynomial transform upon making a substitution into it?

Tags: polynomials, substitution

My title is very poorly worded, I apologise, I'm having a hard time wording the question. My lecturer described it as being obvious, so I must be missing something very fundamental (the substitution is in terms of $a_2$, not $\alpha _2$.)

Thanks for any help!
[image: This is the question]

Upon substituting we get $(2 a_2^3)/27 - (a_2 a_1)/3 + a_0 - (a_2^2 y)/3 + a_1 y + y^3$. When I substitute $y = x + a_2 / 3$ back in it, wolframalpha gives the original polynomial.

I can't see how we'd ever get anything different.

Comment: I'm at least as lazy as you. What does the equation look like when you've done said substitution?

Comment: $y^3 - (a/2)y^2 + (b - a^2/4)y + c - ab/2 + a^3/8$

Comment: So why don't you add this to your question (marking "own effort")? (as I said, I'm at least ... ;-) )

Comment: That's stupid on my part..., I'll fix the question up in a bit, so sorry!

Comment: The polynomial in $y$ is in the desired form.

Comment: But am I not supposed to write it all in terms of $x$, not $y$?

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it is the binomial expansion $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$, you now need the $x^2$ terms to cancel out (the rest of the factors contribute only lower power terms) so setting $3y=a_2$ does the trick.